# Why is tab keyboard navigation not working with tabIndex set?

Tags: html, html-table, contenteditable

Consider this HTML table:

```
<table contenteditable="true">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td tabindex="0"></td>
    <td tabindex="0"></td>
    <td tabindex="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td tabindex="0"></td>
    <td tabindex="0"></td>
    <td tabindex="0"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like the user to be able to tab from cell to cell as he edits the table contents, and to programmatically focus on any given cell. I observed the following behaviors in Chrome, and I'm trying to understand and remedy them:

I don't understand why if I put the cursor in one cell and press the `tab` key, the cursor doesn't go to the next cell.

I don't understand why when I click on a cell, although the cursor shows up and I can edit its contents, focus still seems to be on the table as a whole  rather than that cell specifically (found out by console logging `document.activeElement`)

I don't understand why when I execute `myCell.focus()` in Javascript, the cursor doesn't appear in the cell in question even though the cell becomes the `activeElement` and the table as a whole has `contenteditable="true"`

[**JSFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/eagk6jq1/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For tabbing to work on both Chrome 76 and Firefox 68, I needed to set the table itself to not be editable, but then also set each cell to be editable:

```
<table contenteditable="false">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[**JSFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/65dervhb/)

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to use `input` elements in each `td`s and then use this function:

> js

```
    $('td').bind('keypress', function(event) {
     if(event.which === 9) {
        if ($(this).next().length > 0){
            $(this).next().find("input").focus();
        }else{
             $(this).parent().next().find('td').first().find("input").focus();
        }

});
```

> html

```
<table contenteditable="true">
    <tbody> 
       <tr> 
            <td tabindex="0"><input /></td> 
            <td tabindex="0"><input /></td> 
            <td tabindex="0"><input /></td>
       </tr> 
       <tr> 
            <td tabindex="0"><input /></td> 
            <td tabindex="0"><input /></td>
            <td tabindex="0"><input /></td> 
       </tr> 
    </tbody> 
 </table>
```

Comment: In addition, i think if you use 'inputs' in each 'td' elements, you don't need any js codes. Because the Tab key do that it's self for you. But the function that i wrote, can handle every kies. You just should change 9 with any other kies you want

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I thought about that but it would not fit my needs well.  The table cells need to be able to contain complex elements and markup like images, custom elements etc.. not just text.  Also, I've seen it work with just table cells elsewhere so I believe it can be done.  Finally I don't use jQuery.

Comment: Ok. I thought that your codes are simple as you wrote. Anyway if want to give more helps, i recommended to write your full codes with enough explanation so we can help you

Comment: I think I posted the minimum required to show the problem but maybe you're right.  Even with simple text content though, the inputs have a problem because they don't expand to fit the content the way a table cell does when the user types a lot.  I think I've found a solution to my problem.  I posted it here.